# Capturing an Attachment Returned Using the tSoap Talend Component

Tags: web-services, jasper-reports, jasperserver, talend

I am using the tSoap component in Talend to make a call the the JasperServer web service. The web service returns a PDF as an attachment. I would like to capture this in Talend, but the tSoap component doesn't seem to let me. All I am able to return is a XML soap message which does not contain an attachment. I output the XML to a file, but all I see is the XML.

I tried doing this in tWebServices also, but have the same issue.

Does anyone know if this be done using the tSoap or tWebServices components? Or does it need to be done in another way?

I am using Talend Open Studio for ESB 5.1.

Thanks

Comment: I ended up using a tSystem component to call a PHP script that makes the soap call to Jasper and generates a pdf to the file system.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot test this, because I don't have any webservice returning PDF files on hand.

But you could try this :

1. Setup a `tWebService` component selecting the right operation and parameters
2. On the output mapping, right column, click on Edit Schema
3. Add a column matching your PDF file, and set it with a `Object` type.
4. Link the output to a `tJavaFlex` component and do whatever you want with the Object

I'm not sure that it will work, but it worth trying.

Comment: I can't get the tWebService component working right now.  it's giving me some weird java error.  I think I may need to re-install jdk.  Current only tSoap is working for me.